# onResume is not called when I relaunch the app after home button pressed

Tags: android, lifecycle

So I have my main activity, and when you press a button it launches activity2. Once activity2 is launched I press the home button and it will trigger *onPause* at activity2 and then the desktop of the android device comes to top. Everything's ok.

The problem is: now I click the app icon and instead of coming to top activity2 (the last active), it comes my main activity. So *onResume* is not called on activity2, but on my main activity.

Isn't it supposed to be called *onResume* on activity2? How could I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you launch an application from the home screen launcher, you are specifically launching the activity which that launcher icon corresponds to.

The behavior you are thinking about is more along the lines of what occurs when you re-enter by way of an activity which is in the back stack.

If you want the home screen launcher icon to put you back in whatever activity you were previously in when that is different from the activity that icon is linked to, you'll need to keep track of that and have your launcher activity transfer you there.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure, didn't you override the [onKeyDown](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29) method which is able to catch device buttons?

Comment: No, I didn't override onKeyDown. I thought that onResume would be called on activity2 by default because this was the last active activity, not the launcher activity, but it seems I was wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ***android: launchMode="singleTask"*** from your launcher activity in the manifest file.